# Зачем нужен метод count у класса range

Tags: python, python-3.x, range

Результатом `range` всегда будет уникальные числа, поэтому `range.count(x)` будет возвращать либо `0` либо `1`, такой-же результат можно получить так

```
int(x in range)
```

производительность одинаково, к примеру:

```
int(100000000000000 in range(100000000000001))
```

```
range(100000000000001).count(100000000000000)
```

это в обоих случаях мгновенно вернут `1`, и поэтому возник вопрос, в чем различия этих вариантов и зачем нужен метод `count`

Comment: Ну хз, у меня оба варианта выводят `MemoryError`, не используйте раз не нужен. Если интересно что он делает - читайте документацию

Comment: @ВадимАлександру у вас, наверное, второй питон? В третьем этот код не должен давать MemoryError

Comment: Подозреваю, что метод добавили просто для унификации и, может быть, обратной совместимости, т.к. во втором питоне range возвращал тупо список, у которого этот метод был.

Comment: @Xander действительно. 2.7

Comment: а между 3 и 2 питоном есть обратная совместимость?

Comment: Нету, зачем она?

Comment: Полноценной обратной совместимости нет. Но, думаю, авторы языка при переработке range в третьем питоне всё-таки старались сгладить различия, насколько это возможно и целесообразно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нельзя сказать, что метод `count` именно "нужен". Дело в том, что `range` реализует [абстрактный базовый класс](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/abc.html#module-abc) [Sequence](https://docs.python.org/3.3/glossary.html#term-sequence).

И именно в `Sequence` определен метод `count`. В общем случае в последовательности элементы могут повторяться, поэтому есть этот метод, для подсчета количества. В случае с `range` метод вырожден. Он возвращает `1` если элемент принадлежит `range` или `0` если не принадлежит.

Сам метод может и не особо нужен, но класс должен реализовывать все методы интерфейса, чтобы его можно было использовать во всех контекстах, где можно использовать произвольную последовательность.